# Can I use jQuery to check whether at least one checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML form which can have many checkboxes. When the submit button is clicked, I want the user to get a javascript alert to check at least one checkbox if none are checked. Is there an easy way to do this using jQuery?

```
<form name = "frmTest" id="frmTest">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="true" name="chk[120]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="true" name="chk[128]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[130]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[143]">
  <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You would probably be better off with `<input name="chk[]" value="120">`. Note also that the **only** acceptable value for the checked attribute is "checked". `checked="true"` is an error.

Answer (score 110):

```
if(jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) { … }
```

Comment: @Jan — `jQuery('#frmTest input[type=checkbox]:checked')` returns a jQuery object containing all the elements that match the selector. It does not return a boolean. You might be confusing it with `HTMLInputElement.checked`.

Answer (score 37):

```
$('#frmTest input:checked').length > 0
```

Comment: $('#frmTest:checkbox').length > 0 would be better to check among a certain number of checkboxes.

Comment: Why would radio-buttons be better? If the OP wants *at least* one option selected radio-buttons would limit him to one *at most*.

Comment: @David, I've removed that suggestion.

Answer (score 27):

```
$("#frmTest").submit(function(){
    var checked = $("#frmText input:checked").length > 0;
    if (!checked){
        alert("Please check at least one checkbox");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$("#show").click(function() {
    var count_checked = $("[name='chk[]']:checked").length; // count the checked rows
        if(count_checked == 0) 
        {
            alert("Please select any record to delete.");
            return false;
        }
        if(count_checked == 1) {
            alert("Record Selected:"+count_checked);

        } else {
            alert("Record Selected:"+count_checked);
          }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, something changed in how jQuery handles checkbox checked event?

Answer (score 10):

```js
$('#fm_submit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ck_box = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    
    // return in firefox or chrome console 
    // the number of checkbox checked
    console.log(ck_box); 

    if(ck_box > 0){
      alert(ck_box);
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name = "frmTest[]" id="fm_submit">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="true" >
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="true" >
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <input type="submit" id="fm_submit" name="fm_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#frmTest').submit(function(){
    if(!$('#frmTest input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
      alert("Please check at least one.");
      return false;
    }
});
```

is(':checked') will return true if at least one or more of the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Is it possible for this to check on live checkbox clicks?

Comment: Yes, but you would use a different event handler. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442322/jquery-checkbox-event-handling