# validate all fields of form at once when at least one selection is accpetable

Tags: jquery, validation

I have all kinds of form elements in a form. I have set **mandatory** class for mandatory elements to validate if they are not empty. The class selector works on **input(text)**, **textarea** and **select** but not working on **checkboxs** and **radios**.

I know how can I check for **at least one selection** in a radiogroup or checkbox group ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684434/jquery-check-if-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked)) but I`m looking for a more general method to work only with class.

My exact question: Is there a general way to check all fields (and radios or checkboxes at least one selection) or I have to check radios and checkboxes separately?

my current code for inputs,textarea and select:

```
$(".ajaxform").ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit : function(arr, $form, options){
    var myresult=true;
    $(".mandatory").each(function(){
      if (!($(this).val())){myresult=false}
    });
    return myresult;
  },
  success:showResponse
});
```

Comment: may be i didnt get your exact requirement but are you looking to check if the radio or checkbox is selected and that too without using `:checked` selector ?

Comment: Yes. actually I don't want to check radios and checkboxes separately. even a plugin or a more general method and even using :checked for textareas(!)  to validate all elements by a single method.

Comment: hmm, that seems tricky as you have to check the `checked` property even if you go for native javascript  i mean we still have to check `document.getElementById("myCheck").checked`  to see if it is selected or not

Comment: The second problem is that checkbox or radios are multi choice and one of them is enough and I have not to loop through all of them!

Comment: why not add a class to all those inputs, textareas, checkboxes and radio buttons which are clicked or typed in and then check for that class on those element ?

Comment: you can use `onblur` or `focusout` to check if something was typed in and the value is not empty before adding a class on them.

Comment: Good suggestion. But I have to remove that class for checkboxes and radios when unselected or inputs when cleared! there is another long process to manipulate these events.